# Unable to turn on hyper-v in the firmware for ryzen processor, no option to enable in bios

Tags: hyper-v, bios, amd-processor

My purpose is to set up a virtual linux box and one of the steps it to enable Hyper-V.

I have an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 which says it should be able to enable Hyper-V.

However, I saw no option in the BIOS menu to enable it.

Does anyone know why this could be? Is there another BIOS menu I should be able to access?

These are the BIOS screens I can access, one is "easy mode" and the other is classic. I attached a picture of the classic one. Hyper-V is not mentioned in any of the tabs and they look different than other control panels I see online.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

["thing"[[image: ][1]1]

Comment: So what's your motherboard?  Your PC make and model?  FYI, BIOS "CPU virtualization settings" are one thing.  [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) is a Microsoft product, something altogether different.

Comment: You are looking for "AMD-V" activation in BIOS. Hyper-V is a hypervisor by Microsoft - the software you might be trying to install. However, your question is not about software development, making it off-topic on SO. You might want to try on [su].

Answer (score 1):

You can find it under: “M.I.T” > “Advanced Frequency Settings” > “Advanced CPU Core Settings” > “SVM Mode”.

And for your info, Hyper-V and Virtual Box are two separate Software that does the same thing which is creating virtual machines, and these pieces of software are installed within your operating system.

What you are actually doing now is Enabling Virtualization on your system so you are able to create virtual machines.

Comment: I don't have the OP's chip and I don't know his motherboard/BIOS combination, so I can't confirm... but what you're saying sounds right.  Thank you for your reply: +1.  You might also want to warn the OP about UEFI and Secure Boot: https://www.zdnet.com/article/installing-linux-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware-a-refresher/

Comment: @paulsm4 I have a similar motherboard that has the same bios, That's how I know how to do it.